# Filebeat setup ILM with template and custom name

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Using ES toolchain in version `7.17.0`
I'd like to setup ILM + index_template with customised name.
However from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/change-index-name.html)

```
If index lifecycle management is enabled (which is typically the default), setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern are ignored.
```

It seems like it's not possible.

Now the questions:

- is it ok to setup custom template name (with custom setup) when ILM is/was enabled?
- is it ok to run two setup files in filebeat? (e.g. `filebeat setup --index-management --dashboards -c setup-ilm.yml && filebeat setup --index-management --dashboards -c setup-template.yml`)?
- am I able to put those setup files somewhere in filebeat (docker image) to be execute automatically? I've seen that there is only `modules` and `inputs` folder setup.

when I've executed those setup files above I've seen following:

```
Loading ILM policy and write alias without loading template is not recommended. Check your configuration.
Index setup finished.
Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
Loaded dashboards
ILM policy and write alias loading not enabled.

Index setup finished.
Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
Loaded dashboards
```

setup-ilm.yml

```yaml
setup:
  ilm:
    enabled: true
    policy_file: "ilm-policy.json"
  template:
    enabled: false

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
```

setup-template.yml

```yaml
setup:
  ilm:
    enabled: false
  template:
    enabled: true
    name: "${ES_NAMESPACE:+${ES_NAMESPACE}-}filebeat-%{[agent.version]}"
    pattern: "${ES_NAMESPACE:+${ES_NAMESPACE}-}filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-*"
  kibana:
    host: "kibana:5601"
  index:
    number_of_shards: 1
    mapping:
      total_fields:
        limit: 5000

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did to have custom index name + lifecycle policy, I'm using the elastic operators from ECK so if it's not your case it may be different. So, assuming ECK and elastic are already installed this is my beats yaml file:

```
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: filebeat
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 8.6.0
  config:
    filebeat:
      autodiscover:
        providers:
          - type: kubernetes
            node: ${NODE_NAME}
            hints:
              enabled: true
              default_config:
                type: container
                paths:
                  - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
    output:
      elasticsearch:
        index: "custom-name-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
        hosts: [ "elastic-host:9200" ]
        username: "filebeat_user"
        password: "password" # pending to load from secret
        ssl:
          verification_mode: "none"
    setup:
      template:
        name: "filebeat"
        pattern: "*-filebeat-*"
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata: {}
      - add_host_metadata: {}
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: filebeat
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true # Allows to provide richer host metadata
        containers:
          - name: filebeat
            securityContext:
              runAsUser: 0
            volumeMounts:
              - name: varlogcontainers
                mountPath: /var/log/containers
              - name: varlogpods
                mountPath: /var/log/pods
              - name: varlibdockercontainers
                mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
            env:
              - name: NODE_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        volumes:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            hostPath:
              path: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            hostPath:
              path: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            hostPath:
              path: /var/lib/docker/containers
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
    resources:
      - namespaces
      - pods
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

As I understood, this will create an index template called filebeat that match the pattern `*-filebeat-*` and a policy for that index called filebeat. This is the important part:

```
output:
  elasticsearch:
    index: "custom-name-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    hosts: [ "elastic-host:9200" ]
    username: "filebeat_user"
    password: "password" # pending to load from secret
    ssl:
      verification_mode: "none"
setup:
  template:
    name: "filebeat"
    pattern: "*-filebeat-*"
```

I hope this helps because is poorly documented, they even have an open issue to improve the documentation: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/11866

[image: lifecycle policy working]